# How To Change PDF Invoice Order Name?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

How To Change PDF Invoice Order Name ?

How TO Change Font Site Of Product Name?

[image]

Comment: Is it pdf or email? If its email then probably your question is where is the template to make the changes ..right?

Comment: it is email that display in gmail

Answer (score 1):

If its email then you will find it here `app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\invoice_new.html`.

It looks like default template so you can do the css changes in this file `skin\frontend\base\default\css\email-inline.css`. You can check the `.css` file name inside the template itself.

When you will open the template file `app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\invoice_new.html` then you will find a line like this

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

In your case css file might be different. You need to do the css changes over there. Or you can add inline css in your html.

### EDIT

Now if you want to dig further then check a line

> {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items"
>   invoice=$invoice order=$order}}

This line shows all products in an order. Now go to `sales.xml` and find `sales_email_order_invoice_items` handler (If overridden then you may find it inside your theme). You can check the template inside it which is `email/order/invoice/items.phtml`. Inside this there is another template gets called which is `email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml`. This is the file you need to do your changes. You can find product name, sku etc etc over there.

Comment: i have to change font size as small in order name but i can't find that, where to exactly write to Order Name Display Code ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Kindly check that. And please accept the answer if it helps to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the Font Site Of Product Name in invoice email, go to the below file 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\invoice\default.phtml`

and change the font size in below line:

```
<strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
```